# How could nodes receive packets from sensors and on the other hand send them to Mobile Elements?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using OMNet++ to simulate a wireless network.

The scenario is : "sensor nodes send sensory data to some nodes (called RN)(send to the nearest RN). and some mobile elements collect data from these points." sensors distribute uniform in field and position of RNs are determined.also MEs follow BonnMobility with predefined path.

I'm using omnet 5.4 with inet 3.6.

numHost=500 ** numME=5 ** numRN=50

NED file:

```
network MyNet
{
    parameters:
        int numHost;
        int numME;
        int numRN;
        string hostType = default("WirelessHost");
        string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");
        @display("bgb=600,600;bgu=m");
    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=47,16");
        }
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=398.63998,15.7039995");
        }
        radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=280.256,15.7039995");
        }
        lifecycleController: LifecycleController {
            parameters:
                @display("p=513.4,15.7039995");
        }
        host[numHost]: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            parameters:
                @display("p=300,300;i=device/cellphone");
        }
        ME[numME]: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=577.424,506.152;i=device/pocketpc");
        }
        RN[numRN]: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=300.792,413.136;i=device/server");
        }
        physicalEnvironment: PhysicalEnvironment {
            @display("p=157.04,15.7039995");
        }
        sinkNode: SinkNode {
            @display("p=300,565.344;i=device/antennatower;is=l");
        }
}
```

the question is:

how can i set udp traffic in .ini file? How could RN receive packets from sensors and on the other hand send them to MEs?

After running this simulation, all nodes send packet to all others, provided I set a specific destination node. Is it correct or not?

this is a part of ini file.

```
*.*.networkLayer.arpType = "GlobalARP"

*.host[*].numUdpApps = 1
*.host[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
*.host[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses=moduleListByPath("**.RN[*]")
*.host[*].udpApp[0].destPort = 1000
*.host[*].udpApp[0].messageLength = 100 bytes
*.host[*].udpApp[0].sendInterval = exponential(12s)
*.host[*].udpApp[0].startTime = uniform(0s,10s)
*.host[*].udpApp[0].packetName = "UDPData"


*.RN[*].numUdpApps =2
*.RN[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"       #  or "UDPSink"???
*.RN[*].udpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.RN[*].udpApp[0].destPort = 1001
*.RN[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = moduleListByPath("**.ME[*]")
*.RN[*].udpApp[0].messageLength = 100 bytes
*.RN[*].udpApp[0].sendInterval = exponential(40s)

*.RN[*].udpApp[1].typename = "UDPSink"
*.RN[*].udpApp[1].localPort = 1002 
*.RN[*].udpApp[1].destPort = 1001
*.RN[*].udpApp[1].messageLength = 100 bytes
*.RN[*].udpApp[1].sendInterval = exponential(40s)
*.RN[*].udpApp[1].packetName = "UDPData"


*.ME[*].numUdpApps = 1
*.ME[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPSink"
*.ME[*].udpApp[0].localPort = 1001
```

[NED file](https://bpaste.net/show/b3c4ebb202f2)

[INI file](https://bpaste.net/show/d60a1003b207)

Comment: The expression `moduleListByPath("**.RN[*]")` returns **all** RN nodes in the network. Therefore, in this scenario every host sends a message to all RNs. Is that really your intention?

Comment: Thank you@ Jerzy D. No, I want send sensory data to the nearest RN. Just send to one RN. And RNs send buffered data to just one ME. Also I know there is a problem on rn udpapp. It send data every 40s but I wanna send data when MEs are in their range.Please suggest a solution for this,too.

Comment: How do you determine the nearest host?

Comment: RN with the least distance to the sensor nodes. But I don't know how to set it.

Comment: But what is your idea to determine distance to RN by a sensor node? Do you assume that every sensor node knows RN's coordinates as well as own coordinates? Does the sensor node analyze RSSI or other parameters of signal from RN? Without this idea it is difficult to help you implement it.

Comment: Does nodes know their coordinates after clustering? So If not,  what's your suggestion to simulate this scenario?

Comment: I do not deal with clustering so I am not able to decide whether nodes known their coordinates as well as suggest you the idea of determining the nearest node.

Comment: @jerzy-d. So I should do another trick. I should set RN traffic for a group of sensors but because of high number of nodes, the problem is deploying them orderly in field. How can I put nodes in order of their index in the field? I mean to use `*.host[num1..num2].udpApp[0].destAddresses=RN[index1]`

Comment: @jerzy-d. I mean random initial position for sensors but node[ num1] to node[num2] be in a specific area to ease setting destination traffic.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question about that.