# UDP Application in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

In a network simulation with omnet++5.4 inet 3.6, how can I set a UDP Application in .ini file to send packets from array `A[sizeofA]` to array `B[sizeofB]`?

A and B are two sets of nodes with different sizes and there should be send to the nearest node.

and if there is another set of nodes that called `C[sizeofC]`, how can I set UDP traffic form B to C? I mean B acts as a router here.

appreciate for your help, in advance.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "the nearest node"? `UDP` is transport layer protocol which uses IP addresses, and it doesn't have (and even doesn't require) knowledge about a network topology.

Comment: Thank you @Jerzy D. Suppose a wireless network. Nodes are distributed randomly in the field. Set A nodes send data to the nearest node from set B. And also B nodes send those packets to C set nodes.(B acts as a router) How can I simulate udp traffic?

Comment: To simulate UDP traffic one should set in `omnetpp.ini`: desired UDP application (for example `UDPBasicApp`), ports, destination address, destination port, as well as traffic parameters for selected application (for `UDPBasicApp`: startTime, stopTime, messageLength and sendInterval). These parameters are described in local file `/inet/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UDPBasicApp.ned`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jerzy D. I did it. I asked this question before. Could you ckeck is it correct or not? I gave wrong result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525684/how-could-nodes-receive-packets-from-sensors-and-on-the-other-hand-send-them-to