# choose random initial position for sensors but in a specific area

Tags: omnet++, inet

In a network simulation with omnet++5.4 inet 3.6, I need to choose random initial position for sensors but in a specific area to ease setting destination for UDP Application.

The complete scenario can be watched in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525684/how-could-nodes-receive-packets-from-sensors-and-on-the-other-hand-send-them-to).(consider comments too)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `StationaryMobility` the area may be limited. One may define a rectangle area for a group of hosts, for example:

```
**.host[*].mobilityType = "StationaryMobility"    
**.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

# area 1
**.host[0..9].mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.host[0..9].mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 200m
**.host[0..9].mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.host[0..9].mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 200m

# area 2
**.host[10..19].mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 200m
**.host[10..19].mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 400m
**.host[10..19].mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.host[10..19].mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 200m

# ...
```

Comment: Thank you @jerzy-d. The number of sensors are 500. If I want to have several area(about 150), is there any tricks?

Comment: In `omnetpp.ini` - no. However, you can create own mobility model and achieve the goal fully automatically.